# React - Change static folder path in build directory

Tags: reactjs, react-app-rewired

I am trying to move static folder in build/ to another directory using react-app-rewired. The final result should be build/assets/static. I am stuck for an hours on this one. My config-overrides.js is the following:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.output = {
        ...config.output, // copy all settings
        filename: "assets/static/js/[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "assets/static/js/[name].chunk.js",
    };
    return config;
};
```

Can anyone help me with that. Right now It moves only the js folder from build/static to build/assets/static but I also want to move the media folder with images like this - build/assets/static/media. Thank you